# Find location of None values in nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I need to identify any `None` values in a potentially deeply-nested dictionary, which can also contain lists. Below is my code as it exists now. It works, but it only returns the name of the key directly associated with the `None` value.

I want to have the whole list of keys pointing to the `None`
(e.g. `nested["top_key"]["next_key"]["final_key"]`)

```
def search_for_None(nested):
    for key, value in nested.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            search_for_None(value)
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            for item in value:
                if isinstance(item, dict):
                    search_for_None(item)
        else:
            if value is None:
                logging.error("Missing value for key '{0}'".format(key))
```

Comment: Add an example input data to your question, can make it more clear.

Comment: Your recursive approach is good, but you either need to pass the current "path" along as a parameter, or re-assemble the `None`'s location bit-by-bit with return values (like `return [key] + returned_error_path_list`)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the path along with the recursive call.  Something like below

```
def search_for_None(nested, path):
    for key, value in nested.items():
        dict_path = f"{path}[{key!r}]"
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            search_for_None(value, dict_path)
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            for index, item in enumerate(value):
                list_path = f"{dict_path}[{index!r}]"
                if isinstance(item, dict):
                    search_for_None(item, list_path)
        else:
            if value is None:
                logging.error("Missing value for key '{0}'".format(dict_path))
```

The path parameter should be a string (e.g. "nested")

Also, note that the code you posted (and mine) will not find a None value in a list (e.g. {"a": [None]}) as there's no check for that condition.